# why the BIOS settings did not save on my pc? when I unplug the charger the parameters are lost

Tags: windows, bios, cmos

Asus x553ma 
Windows 8.1 64 bit 
I don't have battery
and asus x553ma do not have CMOS location on motherboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS settings not saving is indicative that the CMOS/BIOS battery needs replacing.

The CMOS battery is a spearate battery, typically a non-user-replaceable part on laptops.

Your laptop model, however, may be user replaceable but it will require the dismantling of the laptop due to the location of the battery on the motherboard.

[image]

Comment: you are correct
no CMOS in my motherboard
I think it is integrated with the motherboard
she does not change. do I have any other solution?

Comment: CMOS batteries *can* usually be replaced but are often soldered to the motherboard and/or difficult to obtain the spare part.

Comment: yes you are correct, thank you very much @Kinnectus